# How to represent a matrix symbolically in R

Tags: r, formula

Consider the following matrix

```
> A
   a  b  k
a  1  0  0
b  0  1  0
c  2  3  0
d -1 -1 10
```

it is to be interpreted as a series of equations:

```
a = a
b = b
c = 2*a + 3*b
d = 10 - a - b
```

I have a function that accepts such a matrix as argument, however it would be nice if the function could accept the equations themselves instead of a matrix and build the matrix using the information supplied via formulas. I have been reading the R documentation about various formula-related functions, including `terms()`, `model.matrix()` and others, and does not look like what I want to do can be done in a straightforward manner.

What do you think, is it doable with a reasonable amount of work or should I ditch the idea?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  I'm completely serious here.  Is there some reason you wish (or are required) to start with equations rather than the matrix elements?  Consider, for example, that you'd need to identify all input and output variables as well as the equations, and enter the equations as strings to avoid parsing them.

Comment: There is no requirement at all, I'm just thinking that equations are more user-friendly than a matrix. Also, because this matrix is actually part of a specification of a model, and most models in R are specified with a formula.

Comment: If you just want to solve a collection of equations, there are several packages, e.g. `BB` that let you do that both directly and with indirect iterative solvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too suspect that there is a different way to solve your problem. However, if you really want to do it this way, you can store your equations as `expression`, and `eval` them at the appropriate time. Here is an example:

```
build.matrix<-function(m, c.expr, d.expr) {
  rbind(m,eval(c.expr),eval(d.expr))
}

a<-c(1,0,0)
b<-c(0,1,0)
m<-rbind(a,b)
c <- expression(2*m['a',]+ 3*m['b',])
d <- expression(10 - m['a',] - m['b',])

build.matrix(m,c,d)

#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# a    1    0    0
# b    0    1    0
#      2    3    0
#      9    9   10
```